# Sequence of functions that converge uniformly on a compact metric space.

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm getting stuck with this problem:

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a compact metric space and $f_n, g_n: \mathbb{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions converge uniformly to $f, g: \mathbb{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, respectively. Show that $\dfrac{f_n(x)}{1+\vert g_n(x) \vert}$ converges uniformly.

So far, I have the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\bigg\vert \dfrac{f_n(x)}{1+\vert g_n(x) \vert} - \dfrac{f(x)}{1+\vert g(x) \vert} \bigg\vert &=& \bigg\vert \dfrac{f_n(x)(1+\vert g(x) \vert) - f(x) (1+\vert g_(x) \vert)}{(1+\vert g_(x) \vert)(1+\vert g(x)\vert)} \bigg\vert\\
&\leq& \big\vert f_n(x) - f(x) + f_n(x)\vert g(x) \vert - f(x) \vert g_n(x) \vert \big\vert\\
&\leq& \big\vert f_n(x) - f(x)\big\vert + \vert g(x) \vert \big\vert f_n(x) - f(x) \big\vert + \vert f(x) \vert \big\vert g(x) - g_n(x) \big\vert
\end{eqnarray*}

But I'm stuck from here. My main question is, can I say that $\vert g(x) \vert$ and $\vert f(x) \vert$ are bounded since $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge uniformly to them on a compact set? If these were continuous functions I feel like I would be okay in showing that they are bounded, since they would then be uniformly continuous functions on on a compact set. But I don't know how to deal with them since I'm not guaranteed they are continuous. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: where is the problem from?

Comment: An exam from my professor.

Comment: You identified the problem: boundedness. I suspect the intention was to have the functions continuous, for otherwise the compactness of the domain would be utterly irrelevant. However, only $f$ needs to be bounded. If you don't throw away the denominator, the factor of $\lvert f(x) - f_n(x)\rvert$ becomes $\frac{1 + \lvert g(x)\rvert}{(1 + \lvert g_n(x)\rvert)(1 + \lvert g(x)\rvert)}$, which is evidently bounded (by $1$). But for unbounded $f$, you can take $f_n =f$ for all $n$, and simple $g_n$ to see that $\frac{f}{1 + \lvert g_n\rvert}$ need not converge uniformly.